# Switch content of div when another div gets hovered on

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover

I'm having trouble getting something like this to work.  I've got a series of DIVS (1 through 8) and when you hover over one div, I want to literally change the contents of one of the other divs with the contents of #replace (which is current set to hidden)
  `<div id="replace" style="visibility:hidden;">Bla Bla Bla</div>`  ​

Here is what I've got so far:

```
$('#1').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $('#2').replaceWith(jQuery('#replace'));
    },
     mouseleave: function(){
        $('#2').replaceWith(jQuery('#2'));
    },
    click: function(){
        $('#2').replaceWith(jQuery('#replace'));
        $('#1').off('mouseleave mouseover');
    }
});
```

Not really having an effect at all - so is my logic bad, how i'm doing it bad, etc...?

Comment: This might come in use, check the official documentation for jQuery effects: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: Can you check the source code after mouseover and see if the content is being replaced. If it is, you probably just need to set the visibility (from hidden to inline or block). Otherwise, post your html as well so someone can help.

Comment: You also have your .on() syntax incorrect. here is a link to jquery's page about the .on function http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Mike the .on syntax is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/agutuk/3/edit)*

```
<div class="box">This is DIV #1 :) </div>
```

Add a class `.box` to all your 8 elements and do:

```
jQuery(function($){
  
  var replaceText = $('#replace').text();
  var memorizeText = '';
  
  $('.box').on({
      mouseenter: function(){
          memorizeText = $(this).next('.box').text();   // memorize text
          $(this).next('.box').text(replaceText);
      },
      mouseleave: function(){
          $(this).next('.box').text( memorizeText );    // restore memorized text
      },
      click: function(){
          $(this).next('.box').text( replaceText );
          $(this).off('mouseleave mouseenter');
      }
  });
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="content">Bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
    <div class="content">Some more text</div>
    <div class="content-alt" style="display: none;">I like fish</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
    <div class="content">Hello there</div>
    <div class="content-alt" style="display: none;">Test 123</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
    <div class="content">Test</div>
    <div class="content-alt" style="display: none;">Hi!</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.page').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        var nextPage = $(this).next('.page');
        nextPage.children('.content').hide();
        nextPage.children('.content-alt').show();
    },
     mouseleave: function(){
        var nextPage = $(this).next('.page');
        nextPage.children('.content').show();
        nextPage.children('.content-alt').hide();
    }
});
```

---

### Original answer

If I understand your question correctly, you can try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="page1"><div class="name">Page 1</div></div>
<div id="page2"><div class="name">Page 2</div></div>
<div id="page3"><div class="name">Page 3</div></div>

<div id="hidden" style="display: none">This is some hidden text</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#page1').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $('#page2 .name').hide().after($('#replace'));
    },
     mouseleave: function(){
        $('#hidden').hide();
        $('#page2 .name').show();
    },
    click: function(){
        $('#hidden').hide();
        $('#page2 .name').show();
        $('#1').off('mouseleave mouseover');
    }
});
```

But I'm not really sure why you are trying to do this. Are you just trying to show and hide some text on mouse over?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the content of a div when another div is moused over -- basically when someone hovers over div 1, I'll change the contents of div 2, when they hover over 2 I'll change the contents of 1, and so on through about 8 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a lot of data on what your HTML structure looks like, the purpose of this, etc. But the following is an example structure that would achieve what you're question refers to -- and it's a bit shorter as writing out a specific handling for every div when they all do the same thing makes it a bit unnecessarily long. Code is below, working example also in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ6d5/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="1" class="replace-me">DIV 1</div>
<div id="2" class="replace-me">DIV 2</div>
<div id="3" class="replace-me">DIV 3</div>
<div id="4" class="replace-me">DIV 4</div>
<div id="5" class="replace-me">DIV 5</div>
<div id="6" class="replace-me">DIV 6</div>
<div id="7" class="replace-me">DIV 7</div>
<div id="8" class="replace-me">DIV 8</div>
<div id="replacementText">REPLACEMENT TEXT</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#replacementText {
    visibility: hidden;
}​
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.replace-me').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).text($('#replacementText').text());
});
$('.replace-me').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).text("DIV "+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

​

Comment: I need to target specifically - ie, div 1 will replace div 2.  But div 2 might replace div 4.  I've got enough to go on now though I think.  Thank you.